# using Path Variables in Apache Camel Rest

Tags: java, web-services, rest, apache-camel

How can i access PathVariables in the Apache Camel Rest module?

I defined a route like this (following "using base path" from the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html)):

```
rest("/customers/")
.get("/{id}").to("direct:customerDetail")
```

How can i get a hold on the `{id}`-Parameter in the following route?

Basically i would like to know what camel offers instead of `@PathVariable` (see following example)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customers/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Customer customerDetail(@PathVariable String cId) {
    return getCustomer(cId);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Turns out that this is really easy:

```
public Customer customerDetail(Exchange exchange){
    String id = exchange.getIn().getHeader("id").toString();
    return getCustomer(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`${header.id}` works.

try using log:
`.log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "${header.id}");`